# script only firing on text link, not span

Tags: javascript

first post so go easy on my noobness!

I have a script that opens a popup window when some linked text is clicked, but now I want to get rid of the text and just use an empty span with background img as the link. Needless to say the script will not work with just the span and I'd appreciate some pointers on how to modify it to work (or suggest any workarounds if it ain't gonna work on an empty span).

Current link structure (which uses the text link to trigger the js window containing thelink.com):

```
<a href="http://thelink.com" class="pop">
<span class="icon_bg"><!-- empty span with image as background --></span>
some text here
</a>
```

Desired link structure (no text, just empty span with bg img):

```
<a href="http://thelink.com" class="pop">
<span class="icon_bg"><!-- empty span with image as background --></span>
</a>
```

Current script:

```
function popWin() {

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
}
function init() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.pop');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        popWin.addEvent(links[i], 'click', popWin.popup)
    }
}
function openPopup(e) {
    var top = (screen.availHeight - 500) / 2;
    var left = (screen.availWidth - 500) / 2;
    var e = (e ? e : window.event);
    var target = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement);

    var popup = window.open(
        target.href, 
        'social',
        'width=550,height=420,left='+ left +',top='+ top +',location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1'
    );
    if(popup) {
        popup.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
return {
    init: init,
    popup: openPopup,
    addEvent: addEvent
}}
var popWin = new popWin();
popWin.addEvent(window, 'load', popWin.init)
```

My hunch is to somehow define the span tag as the target using .nodeName. All help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using two different elements to catch the same event? Get rid of the <a> and just put your text in the span, catch the click event and replace the span.innerHTML property with the image.

Comment: my goal is to not have any text in that span at all. I'm using the span simply as an image location, setting its width and height and defining its background image. So I want to try and have the js triggered by the span tag as opposed to any text.

Comment: Why not use an img tag, then? The span really appears to be redundant here. All you need is `<a href="thelink.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/path" /></a>` or have I misunderstood what you are trying to do? If the `target="_blank"` won't do what you want then just catch the `onclick` event on your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<span>&nbsp</span>` to simulate invisible text and thus will cause the span to get width.

Comment: tried that and although it does open the popup window, that window is empty (href not being parsed) for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your span is empty currently. Add some content to it, then it would work for you.

```
<span>Content</span>
```

Now the event would trigger for you.

Background image won't be visible until you have some width and height for the span. I would refer you to use

```
span {
   /* change the display property of span; default is inline */
   display: inline-block;
   /* because width and height can be applied to only block level elements */
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Now try it again. Have my fiddle, it makes a good use of your example, and it enables click on the textless span.

Also, you're not having any click handler in your code.

```
<span onclick="popWin()">
```

This would enable the click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/FdjZy/

Comment: Probably didn't make myself clear... I want the span to be an image (using background property) without any text in it. In other words, I need the click to be triggered on a text-less element. I edited the question to highlight this.

Comment: @wordfool, have a look now.

Comment: my span is already definied with a width and height but the js is still not working. Here's the style for the span I'm using: 'width:32px;
 height:32px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url("../img/sprite.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 vertical-align: middle; '

Comment: Then just add this code, `<span onclick="popWin()">` you were not having any click handler.

Comment: tried that already but clicking on the span is still opening just a blank popup window. If I click on the linked text after the span the popup window is populated, but if I click on the span itself the window's blank.

Comment: OK, I think I've worked out the solution, but am curious if this is gonna be bombproof (seem to work in the few browsers I've tried so far). Changed the line:
        'var target = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement)'
to:
        'var target = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement).parentNode;'

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've worked out the solution, but am curious if this is gonna be bombproof (seems to work in the few browsers I've tried so far).

Changed the line:

```
  var target = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement)
```

To:

```
  var target = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement).parentNode;
```

Now the span tag is triggering the script without the need for any text anywhere within the a tags.